# Add a new element in each array of objects where array may have different length in mongodb

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a following shema.

```
{
id:week
output:{
    headerValues:[
        {startDate:"0707",headers:"ID|week"},
        {startDate:"0715",headers:"ID1|week1"},
        {startDate:"0722",headers:"ID2|week2"}
        ]
    }
}
```

I have to add a new field into headerValues array like this:

```
{
id:week
output:{
    headerValues[
        {startDate:"0707",headers:"ID|week",types:"used"},
        {startDate:"0715",headers:"ID1|week1",types:"used"},
        {startDate:"0722",headers:"ID2|week2",types:"used"}
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried different approaches like this:
1)

```
db.CollectionName.find({}).forEach(function(data){
    for(var i=0;i<data.output.headerValues.length;i++) {
      db.CollectionName.update({ 
         "_id": data._id,          "output.headerValues.startDate":data.output.headerValues[i].startDate 
     },
     {
         "$set": {
           "output.headerValues.$.types":"used"
         }
     },true,true
      );
  }
})
```

So, In this approach it is executing script and then failing. It is updating result with failed statement.

2)
Another approach I have followed using this link:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

```
db.collectionName.update({"_id":"week"},
    { "$set": { "output.headerValues.$[].types":"used"   }
})
```

But it fails with error:

> cannot use the part (headerValues of output.headerValues.$[].types) to
>   traverse the element ({headerValues: [ { startDate: "0707", headers:
>   "Id|week" } ]}) WriteError@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:469:48
>   Bulk/mergeBatchResults@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:836:49
>   Bulk/executeBatch@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:906:13
>   Bulk/this.execute@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:1150:21
>   DBCollection.prototype.updateOne@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:550:17
>   @(shell):1:1

I have searched with many different ways which can update different arrays object by adding new field to each object but no success. Can anybody please suggest that what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is {"_id" : "week"}  but in your data *id field is week*

So you can change **{"_id" : "week"} to {"id" : "week"}** *and also update your mongodb latest version*

```
db.collectionName.update({"id":"week"},
   { "$set": { "output.headerValues.$[].types":"used"   }
})
```

Comment: I guess it's mainly the version issue. My current mongo version is 3.4 and this $[] will apply to 3.6 version. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes, it supports only >=3.6 versions.